PIL paste is giving me transparent pixels instead of destination image pixels where the RGBA mask alpha is zero
V3.png:

A7.png:

#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open(r"V3.png")
img2 = Image.open(r"A7.png")
img1.paste(img2, (0,0), mask = img1)
img1.show()

img1.save("output.png")

I expect the resulting image to be exactly V3 with just A7 non-transparent pixels over the green part only. Instead the non-transparent pixels of V3 are being overwritten with A7 pixels, whether transparent or not.
To be clear, I expect this:

But output.png is this:

I have checked the output image transparent pixels, just to be sure, and they're all white with alpha zero.
I have tried calling paste with and without the "mask = " keyword.
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: I'm okay accepting a python solution that doesn't make use of PIL.
UPDATE 1:
I think it's me. It's working as intended, just not as what I thought it would work.
The source pixels are being copied over destination when alpha is 255. This effectively means the destination pixels are being substituted by the source pixels even if the latter are transparent, instead of being preserved when the source pixels are transparent.
I think I need to perform an intermediate step to build the mask I need for this case or perhaps perform two paste operations.
So the title is wrong. The alpha is 255 when this unwanted effect happens.
UPDATE 2:
I think I need to perform a logical AND operation on the two images alpha values to build my mask. Any idea how to do this?

Sorry, I don't know how to reduce image size in the post.

At last I solved it by pasting twice, because the first time around the necessary mask is already generated:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open(r"V3.png")
img2 = Image.open(r"A7.png")
mask = img1.copy()
mask.paste(img2, (0,0), img1)
img1.paste(img2, (0,0), mask)

img1.show()


What happened to SO? Before one would get an answer or comment within minutes.

I'm unsure about the blended pixels with alpha values between 1 and 254 both included tho, because they might be being copied over twice. But I don't think this will be a problem for my use case.

"What happened to SO?" My guess is that folks get disincentivised to answer because too many people ask questions and never log in again, or get a good answer and don't bother saying thank you or upvoting or accepting the answer.
